# Recording modified records in a separate table

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Currently I am recording data in a table, 'modules' with 15 columns, 3 of those are TEXT columns that could take hold 200-500~ words, the rest simple <5 words and an ID key.

I want to duplicate the information entered into a row into the 'modules' table into a new table, we will call it 'version_control_modules', when a user makes any changes to the original 'modules' row entry. However over the period of a year the 'version_control_modules' table may have up to 50+ changes that could possible be saved when people make small changes to the 'modules' table. And this would only be for 1 'module'.

So my question is this - should I become concerned with any performance related issue (response time) since this table will grow to become very vast quite quickly.

Comment: 1) how many row this table may include max. 2) how many request (hit) takes pages related with this table. nobody can not say anything before knowing first 2 thing. 3) about duplicating: please check database normalization rules. you may not duplicate/separate or combine tables against the database normalization rules. I mean of course practically you may, but technically this will cause you bigger problems in the future.

Comment: 1) the 'modules' table could have up to 1000~ modules. 2) 500~ users. 3) Surely I would need to duplicate to have this version control feature?

Comment: oh, I understand now...  I think you must separate "versions" table from "modules" table, according to database normalization rules. there will be two table master/detail (1 to n) related. modules=master table and versions=details...

Comment: Yes 'versions' and 'modules' table will be both seperate, 'versions' will be accessed by inserting the 'modules' primary key into 'versions' . However, do you think I should become concerned with performance issues with these numbers?

Comment: this (separating tables) will increase (positive effect) the performance... other than that, number of records is not huge for effecting application performance, I think. I have some apps which work with several millions of mysql records without any performance issue